# Detecting if an image edge is almost a straight line or not

Tags: python, opencv

How to determine if the edge of an image is almost a straight line?

Say the input image 1 and image 2 below, the program will identify that image 1 has almost a straight line then image 2 is not.

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cv2.HoughLinesP()` to detect lines. Look at the bottom for the result. On the other pictures, it returned no lines. You will need *some* consistency between your pictures, because you will need to adjust the `min_line_length` etc.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
img = cv2.imread('straight.jpg').astype(np.uint8)
m_list = list()
x_list = list()
y_list = list()


edges = cv2.Canny(img,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 1, np.pi/360, 10,
                        minLineLength=30, maxLineGap=1)

if lines is not None:
    for line in lines:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = np.maximum(1, line[0])
        if x1 == x2:
            x2 += 1
        if y1 == y2:
            y2 += 1
        m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
        if not math.isinf(m):
            m_list.append(m)
        x_list.append([x1, x2])
        y_list.append([y1, y2])
        cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), [122, 122, 255], 2)
    print('{} lines identified.'.format(len(lines)))
else:
    print('No lines identified.')
    m_list = 0
    x_list = 0
    y_list = 0
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

```
1 lines identified.
```

[image]